# SSIS import of Excel File

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to import an Excel file into SQL Server SSIS/Visual Studio

I am running a 64 bit Windows Install

Excel 2016 64 bit

Visual Studio Professional 2019

I keep getting the error :- "The requested ole db provider microsoft.ace.oledb.16.0 is not registered. If the 32-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 64-bit mode."

I have tried running both the 32 bit and 64 bit "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable" separately

I have also set the Run64BitRuntime option to "True" and "False" depending on my bit version of Database Engine install but still getting the same error message.

I cannot save Excel as an older version as some posts suggest due to company standards.

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Visual Studio is a 32 bit application, so it'll always try to use the 32 driver, because it's "helpful" like that... If you've installed the 32bit driver for Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable then using version 16 isn't going to help; the 2010 release was version 12.

Comment: Why would you expect the 2010 version would resolve this error? A simple Google provides the correct [Office365 download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).